# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056) in Windows Container Python

Tags: python, azure-storage-account, windows-container

Im running Python scripts inside a windows container and encounter the following error

`ServiceRequestError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)`

I am using the following `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient`

Container Base Image --- python3.7.2windows:ltsc2019-202302

Issue doesn't happen on my local machine

**What I have tried:**

- used latest certifi package version `pip install --upgrade certifi`
- Enabled Port 80 (TCP) , Port 443 (TCP) in the Azure Container Instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Windows Container Image i used does not have the Trusted Root Certificates.

How i fixed it:

1. On my local machine - Run MMC ( Microsoft Management Console). File>Add/Remove Snap In> Certificates
2. Look for the certificate(s) that is related to the error
   In my case i found it in the /Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder
3. Export those certificate(s)( in my case i used .cer format) and added them in a folder inside my solution.
4. The .cer files are then imported when building the windows container image

Here are the Dockerfile - Powershell commands that I used to import for both LocalMachine and CurrentUser Certificate Stores.

```
RUN Import-Certificate -FilePath "\MySolution\CertificateFolder\ExportedCertificate.cer" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\Root

RUN Import-Certificate -FilePath "\MySolution\CertificateFolder\ExportedCertificate.cer" -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\Root
```